# Sort in Collectives Page always sets to Newest

Tags: bug, status-planned, collectives, sorting

The Questions sort in the collectives page doesn't show the applied sort and is always set in "newest". The sorting selected seems to be applied. However, the user cant easily figure out which sorting is currently applied or go back to sorting by 'newest'.

Attached is a screen recording to show the bug.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the Borg forgot to set a `selected` attribute on one of the options of the `#sort-select` select, or incorrectly form the URL that the page is redirected to on change.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! Thanks to your screengrab I was able to reproduce it :), thanks a lot for it. This is a bug that applies to users that aren't member of a Collective. We'll fix it and will update this question whenever that's done.

Comment: @JD-Stack It happens even if you're a member of the collective (at least for me).

Comment: Interesting, it doesn't happen with my regular account... Probably some other combination of circumstances. I guess the devs will figure that out :).

Comment: I believe this bug may have been fixed with a recent feature update. Haven't been able to recreate it, at least, but let me know if it's still happening.

Comment: @sunnybrie yes.. I am not able to repro this again. It looks like this is fixed. Thank you!